# Alternative approaches to addressing JavaScript scoping issues

Tags: javascript, scope

As of now, I've been using self-executing anonymous functions in order to avoid having variable naming issues:

```
(function () {
    var a, b, c;
    a = 5;
    b = 10;
    c = 15;
    console.log('No problema!');
]());
```

I also know that using the onload function is also an alternative approach:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var a;
    a = 25;
    console.log('Yay!!!');
}
```

But I really dislike how my code is completely trapped inside a function - is there an approach that I could take with JavaScript objects that could help me avoid using self-executing functions?

Comment: What do you want the code to look like?

Comment: @SomeKittens can you elaborate a little more by what you mean? I'll clarify my question a little bit more based on your response.

Comment: There's nothing technically wrong with what you have now.  Do you want to declare and assign a variable at one time?  Do you want to use the same variable in different functions?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @SomeKittens I'm trying to create a webapp that requires creating multiple JavaScript modules. Each of these modules will have properties with the exact same names (i.e. width). Placing each of these modules into their own self-executing anonymous functions work if each of them are self-contained. But I oftentimes need to reference these modules too, but since they're self-executing, those variables no longer exist after execution. Hence I can't access them.

Comment: Sounds like what you really want are _objects_ each with their own `width` property.

Comment: @RayToal Is that good practice in your opinion if I'd have more than 20 variables per object?

Comment: Twenty local variables in a function, twenty properties in an object, twenty objects within a module, etc. all seem like a lot to me.  IMHO there are usually ways to simplify such things so that they "do one thing and do it well."  Grouping things together and refactoring can keep things smaller.  It is almost possible with a bit of work, and you feel much better when you get there. :)

Comment: @RayToal Yeah you're right. Refactoring is key. It's just that in d3.js, it's impossible to avoid having 10+ local variables, because you're declaring width, height, scales, axes, paddings, hooks, etc. It's a big dilemma at this point.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much if a library constrains you; if an element has a large number of properties like those you mention you are probably okay (elements have size, position, layout, and visual properties).  If you have the freedom to group the properties somehow to reduce the number of "top-level" properties for an object, that would be nice.  But if it doesn't work it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most of today's browsers, functions simply *are* the unit of encapsulation.  If you want to create a scope for a variable, you make it local to a function.

But today with many server side JavaScript installations, modules exist, many based on [require.js](http://requirejs.org/).  If you write apps with Nodejs, you'll be familiar with it already.

The next version of JavaScript is coming soon, though.  Named ES6, ES.next, Harmony, or JavaScript.next, this new JavaScript will have modules for your information hiding, as well as block scope.  Many browsers are starting to implement features of the language now.  You can experiment with in at http://repl.it, among other places.  You can use Google's [Traceur compiler](http://code.google.com/p/traceur-compiler/) to compile a language including many of the ES6 proposals into today's JavaScript.

TL;DR: for now: stick with functions in the browser.  Or use require.js for your server side applications.  Hang on because ES6 is coming.

Answer (score 1):

```
var MyObject = (function() {
    var _variableHidden = 1;

    return {
        variableVisible: 2
    };
})();

MyObject.variableVisible //= 2
MyObject._variableHidden //= undefined
```

This is called the "Reavealing Module Pattern". It allows you to use scoping to hide variables while still making properties and methods available by attaching them to a returned object. You can read more about this pattern, and others, here: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript

While this approach doesn't remove "self-executing" functions, it does allow you to keep the gains of scoping and variable hiding while making things available to outside scopes.

I should also note that they are not self-executing functions. They don't execute themselves. We actually do that for them :). Just a pet-peeve of mine, haha.